# Using DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<> in a generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

I am writing a library that works alongside XNA.  I have a base class for primitives, from which I plan to build Planes, Cubes and other primitive-types.  Ideally I'd like my base class to do the rendering, regardless of the vertex-type used.

Relevant code:

```
public abstract class Primitive<VT> where VT : IVertexType
{
    private void Draw(GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {
            graphics.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VT>(primitiveType_, 
                                                   vertices_, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   vertices_.Length, 
                                                   indices_, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   primitiveCount_);
    }    
}
```

Now, other classes than derive from this, using the appropriate vertex-type:

```
public abstract class Plane<VT> : Primitive<VT> where VT : IVertextTpye { ... }
public class PlaneColored : Primitive<VertexPositionColor> { .... }
public class PlaneTextured : Primitive<VertexPositionTexture> { .... }
```

The problem is, I get a compile error on the DrawUserIndexPrimitives<> call:

```
Error   1   The type 'VT' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<T>(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PrimitiveType, T[], int, int, short[], int, int)'  C:\dev\Projects\2010\XNAParts\XNAParts\Parts\Primitive.cs   88
```

And I can't change the construct to a `struct` otherwise the DrawUserIndexPrimitives' generic parameter won't work (as it's not a struct).

Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good question but the title does not describe the real problem with null constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just changing `Primitive` to require that `VT` is a struct?

```
public abstract class Primitive<VT> where VT : struct, IVertexType
```

and similarly

```
public abstract class Plane<VT> : Primitive<VT> where VT : struct, IVertexType
```

You claim that "DrawUserIndexPrimitives generic parameter won't work (as it's not a struct)" but it's not clear what you mean by that. Which parameter? I *suspect* the above is what you want, but it's not really clear.

Comment: Thanks for this, I totally forgot one could use both struct and IVertextType!